# Vue cli 3 - Cannot find module '@vue/cli-plugin-babel'

Tags: typescript, babeljs, web-component, vue-cli-3

I am using vue cli 3 with typescript support. Actually, i'm trying to create web component using vuejs.

**main.ts**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import './plugins/vuetify';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';
import wrap from '@vue/web-component-wrapper';

import RoleManagement from './views/role-management/RoleManagement.vue';

const CustomElement = wrap(Vue, RoleManagement);
window.customElements.define('custom-component', CustomElement);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

Command to create web component is as follows,

*vue-cli-service build --target wc --name custom-component ./src/main.ts*

After this getting error,

**Cannot find module '@vue/cli-plugin-babel'**

Comment: check your package.json file for package "@vue/cli-plugin-babel". If it is not there, then install it and try again.

Comment: It's already there...

Comment: have you managed to solve this?

Comment: This issue is re-occuring it seems. The weird thing is that in the babel config it wants `@vue/cli-pluginS-babel/preset`, with emphasis on the S, as the package name is without the S. Don't know if this has any bearing on it..

Comment: It is Sep 2021, I still stumble on this problem, though I remember it used to work on this computer (with different updted version). As @Nickvda mentioned I do have the same problem but without the uppercase S. Nowadays, my Version of is @vue/cli-plugin-babel ^3.12.1

Answer (score 1):

facing this issue with v3.1.2 but it works when i downgrade to v3.1.0 (with a warning that this version is no longer maintained) a temporary work around.This can be a possibility to your problem

Comment: It's not working if project is created with command 'vue create my-project'.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that doesn't run when the `vue-cli-service` is called directly.
Somehow it can be *workarounded* by calling via *npm script*.

Why don't you try setting

```
scripts: {
   build: "vue-cli-service build"
}
```

in your `package.json` and try later with

```
npm run build --target wc --name custom-component ./src/main.ts
```

Comment: This answer sounds weak to me. I am not having any *.ts scripts at all. The 'try setting' is automatically done in the first first place by the vue create project setup with vue3 anyways. Answer Downgrade for me.